# How do I fix my display resolution problem on Ubuntu 20.10 Raspberry Pi?

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr, 20.10

My monitor has a resolution of 136**8**x768. In the Ubuntu settings page, there's no option for my display resolution nor 136**6**x768. All of the options have the top bar cut out or the dock. I used xrandr to add the option into the settings page, then tried it again and it worked fine. However, whenever I reboot the resolution resets to 720p (which cuts out the top bar AND part of the dock) so anyone know how to permanently keep the resolution as-is(1368x768 by using xrandr)?